# Pros and cons of leaving out non-retina images?

Tags: ios, retina-display

Since including non-retina images is such a time sink, I thought I should ask...
What are some pros and cons of not having non-retina images in your apps? Is the downsizing the Apple does inferior to the usual downsizing that Photoshop does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros:

1. Less work for you.
2. Devices are generally trending to retina display (definitely true of the handsets, tablets are not there yet).

Cons:

1. You don't get to tailor images to the smaller grid. Most good designers like to do this so the gist of a (say) small icon isn't lost in the naive downsample.
2. You either aren't supporting non-retina devices, or you're (maybe) rolling the dice with memory/GPU in making them load much larger textures. How big a deal the latter is depends on what your app is like and what you're doing with images, and also what devices you're targeting. A full-screen image on an iPad retina would absolutely hobble an iPad 1, and probably make iPads 2 and minis unhappy as well.
3. Even if you're batch downsampling as a build step as @SK9 suggests, you could control the sampling technique. What you'd get by "default" depends on if you're using `UIImageView` or GL or...

Comment: "Devices are generally trending to retina display (definitely true of the handsets, tablets are not there yet)." I almost committed to writing that myself, but before too long we'll have super-retina and @4x, whereupon this problem comes back.

Answer (score 1):

> Since including non-retina images is such a time sink, ...

Why is that? You can write a shell script around [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to generate the non-retina images. You can even add this to your build flow. The results are passable; they're better if the lower resolution images are done by hand. See [here](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/).

Or, if you're really not happy using the command line, you can open your images directory in Finder, command-select every image, duplicate, open all duplicates in Preview, select all in preview, and scale down there.

Better to use the command line approach though, it's far superior for getting a large job done efficiently.

In any case, the cost of including non-retina images is at worst one-time and can be amortised. Just be sure they're all of even width and height for trouble free scaling down.

Comment: Just a random thought. Why not omit the non-retina images from the app since almost every device is retina now? It will decrease the content size present in the app.

Comment: You can, that's an option. How will you handle @2x versus @3x when the time comes? Android already has `xxhdpi`, where `xhdpi` compares with iOS retina @2x, and is comparable to "@3x".

Comment: Also note that `@2x` has four times as many pixels as `@1x`. You could leave out `@1x` resources, but it won't save you an awful lot. If you're worried about these things, Google ImageOptim and ImageAlpha.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime downsizing doesn't actually change the amount of data that is loaded, so it doesn't change the amount of memory used. So, if your images are large and you have a lot of them you might just crash on older devices as you'll use up all of the available memory. If you don't crash just for that then you will certainly make life more difficult while the app is running and doing other processing.